# How to specifying different ports for multiple host in cssh?

Tags: telnet

I am using `cssh` to telnet into multiple hosts at the same time.

I have changed the `ssh=/usr/bin/telnet` to point to the telnet program.

The problem I am facing is that each host uses different port for telnet.

I tried the following format but it did not work

```
cssh host1:100 host2:200 host3:300
```

How do I specify different port numbers for the different host?

Answer (score 0):

First off why are you creating an alias for ssh to point to telnet?  I believe you can just use ctel as described below in the man page for cssh:

> Connections are opened via ssh so a correctly installed and configured
>   ssh installation is required. If, however, the program is called by
>   "crsh" then the rsh protocol is used (and the communications channel
>   is insecure), or by "**ctel**" then telnet is used.

Here is the syntax for it: `ctel [options] [<server>[:port]|<tag>] [...]`

So you should be able to get it to work by using:

ctel host1:100 host2:200 host3:300

Comment: I tried after changing the value of "ssh" in .csshrc, but the following error is thrown when specifying the port: Testing comms - running command:
/usr/bin/telnet   -p 23 x.x.x.x echo Working
/usr/bin/telnet: invalid option -- p
Looks like ctel is trying to pass -p option to telnet which is not valid.

Comment: When I tried creating a link to cssh from ctel, without editing the .csshrc file, the command is still trying to invoke ssh : /usr/bin/ssh -x -o ConnectTimeout=10  -p 23 x.x.x.x

Comment: Looks like it was a bug fixed in later versions of cssh. I am using RHEL 5.8 and find no packages with the fix. I am not sure how to build one myself.

Comment: You could just do the same thing with a simple bash script.  Make a list of Hosts on the network then:  For i in LIST; do telnet HOST1 echo Working done